# How to access Apache from IOS using HTTPS with authentication SSL?

Tags: ios, apache, ssl, ca

I have done a new installation of the latest version of Mac OS X (10.12.5).
This versión of Mac include Apache 2.4.25 (Unix)

In that Apache I have configured two virtualhost:

- Virtual host 1. example.com
  (80 - http)
- Virtual host 2. private.example.com
  (443 –https – With Two-way authentication SSL)

  Mac OS X has an old version of OpenSSL (0.9.8zh), so to create certificates selfsigned (CA, Server Cert and Client Cert), I've used a Debian distribution with OpenSSL version 1.0.1t. This is because of this:
  https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207459

In both virtualhost I have created an index.html file to check that everything works fine.

Virtual host 1. (80 - http) index.html (works perfectly in all systems and browsers)

Virtual host 2. (443 - https - With Two-way authentication SSL) (works perfectly in all systems and browsers)

Apparently everything works fine. I have tested from web browsers of computers (Chrome, Firefox and Safari) and web browsers of mobile phones (Android & Iphone - Chrome and Safari).

But now I've created a video file in mp4 format on every virtualhost called video.mp4. In theory it should be reproduced well in both virtualhosts. But in private.example.com, only in IOS (last versión, 10.3.2) does not work any web browser (Safari and Chrome)

Virtual host 1. (80 - http) video.mp4 (works perfectly in all systems and browsers)

Virtual host 2. (443 - https - With Two-way authentication SSL) video.mp4   (does not work in iOS)

The apache logs say nothing, but if you enable debugging mode you find several information. The most notorious is this:

"AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server private.example.com:443)"

"SSL Library Error: error:140890C7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate -- No CAs known to server for verification?"

Any ideas?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.